# Logical And operator in the for loop

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am Writing one script

It will access all the variables from one file and will use those variables in another script

In the var.sh file

```
MYSQL_LOGIN_USER="admin"
MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD="admin@123"   
declare -a MYSQL_USERS=("abc" "xyz") # declaring an array for mysql users
declare -a MYSQL_PASSWD=("abc@123" "xyz@123") #declaring an array for mysql passwords
MYSQL_DATABASE="database"
```

**I Want to access both the array declared in var.sh file**

In the main.sh file

```
source var.sh
echo "create database $MYSQL_DATABASE" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
for i in "${MYSQL_USERS[@]}"
do
  echo "CREATE USER $i" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
  echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MYSQL_DATABASE.* TO $i IDENTIFIED BY $i" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
done
```

**In the above script I have used same name for user and password while granting privilages**

*I have tried using logical AND [&&] in the for loop but it is not working*

*Do i have to use nested for loops??*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlastairCampbell is almost correct, but you need to index the arrays:

```
for i in "${!MYSQL_USERS[@]}"
do
    echo "CREATE USER ${MYSQL_USERS[$i]}" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
    echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MYSQL_DATABASE.* TO ${MYSQL_USERS[$i]}" IDENTIFIED BY ${MYSQL_PASSWD[$i]}" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
done
```

Note that there are other issues with this script:

- You should use `$(printf %q "$variable")` to allow for special characters in any external variables.
- You can pass in SQL as a parameter rather than on standard input:

  ```
  mysql -u $(printf %q "$MYSQL_LOGIN_USER") -p$(printf %q "$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD") "CREATE USER $(printf %q "${MYSQL_USERS[$i]}")"
  ```
- Nitpick, but you don't need to `declare -a` when assigning a literal - Bash figures that out automatically.

Comment: Thanks it is useful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can access the other array directly while in the loop if you get the count of the arguments rather than the arguments themselves.

Like so:

```
source var.sh
echo "create database $MYSQL_DATABASE" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
for i in "${#MYSQL_USERS[@]}"
do
    echo "CREATE USER $MYSQL_USERS" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
    echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MYSQL_DATABASE.* TO $MYSQL_USERS IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQL_PASSWD" | mysql -u $MYSQL_LOGIN_USER -p$MYSQL_LOGIN_PASSWORD
done
```

Hope this helps. Please mark as correct answer if this answers your question.